# Combine file modified date and "grep" results through "find", in one line

Tags: linux, sed, grep, locale, gnu-findutils

We want to show each file's modified date and time when applying `grep` to selected files by the `find` command. The final result should look like:

> `2016-10-17 Mon 20:38:57 ./rest/47results.php: 5 :σχόλια, ιδέες facebook`

Running the following from 47test.php file:

```
system('export TZ=":Europe/Athens"; find . -name "*.*" \
-not \( -path ./admin -prune \) \
-not \( -path ./people/languages -prune \) \
-not \( -path ./include -prune \) \
-type f -mmin -10 \
-printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %Ta %TH:%TM:%TS %p\n" \
-exec grep -HTni "σχόλια" {} + ');
```

we get distinct lines printed **for each modified file and each line**:

```
2016-10-17 Mon 21:09:55.0000000000  ./47test.php
2016-10-17 Mon 20:40:30.0000000000  ./places/00testout.txt
2016-10-17 Mon 20:38:57.0000000000  ./rest/47results.php
./47test.php:  22  :-exec grep -HTni "σχόλια" {} + ');
./rest/47results.php:  5  :σχόλια, ιδέες facebook
./rest/47results.php:  6  :σχόλια, ιδέες twitter
./rest/47results.php:  7  :Τα σχόλια σας
```

One for each `find` and one for each `grep` result.

As mentioned in the beginning, **how can one print sorted, combined results in just one line for each `grep`**?

> ```
> 2016-10-17 Mon 21:09:55 ./47test.php  22  :-exec grep -HTni "σχόλια" {} + ');
> 2016-10-17 Mon 20:38:57 ./rest/47results.php:  5  :σχόλια, ιδέες facebook
> 2016-10-17 Mon 20:38:57 ./rest/47results.php:  6  :σχόλια, ιδέες twitter
> 2016-10-17 Mon 20:38:57 ./rest/47results.php:  7  :Τα σχόλια σας
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `find+grep` combination to get the formatted result:

```
while IFS=$'\06' read -r -d '' t f; do
   sed "s/^/$t /" <(grep -HTni 'σχόλια' "$f")
done < <(find . -type f -mmin -10 -not \( -path ./admin -prune \) \
         -not \( -path ./people/languages -prune \) \
         -not \( -path ./include -prune \) \
         -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %Ta %TH:%TM:%.2TS\06%p\0')
```

- Note use of `\06` as field delimiter to address filenames/paths with whitespaces/newlines etc.
- `\0` (NULL) is used as line terminator for the same reason.
- `%.2TS` is used to trip fractional part of the second value.
- `sed` is used to insert date/time at line start of `grep` output.

---

**PHP Code:**

```
$cmd = <<<'EOF'
export TZ=":Europe/Athens"; \
find . -type f -mmin -10 -not \( -path ./admin -prune \) \
       -not \( -path ./people/languages -prune \) \
       -not \( -path ./include -prune \) \
       -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %Ta %TH:%TM:%.2TS\06%p\0' |
while IFS=$'\06' read -r -d '' t f; do grep -HTni 'σχόλια' "$f" | sed "s/^/$t /"; done
EOF;

// var_dump( $cmd );

echo shell_exec($cmd) . "\n";
```

Comment: I enclosed everything in the existing `system(" ...... ");` but unfortunately I got (instead of results) the following: **Warning:  system(): NULL byte detected. Possible attack in /home/...../47test.php on line 28**. Did I put something in the wrong place?

Comment: It feels like quite "intense" for the server. I mean it takes a while (about 10sec) to print the results. Other than that. **Works like a charm**. Not even in my wildest dreams. Thank you so much.