# How to combine two commands in -exec parameter of find?

Tags: bash, grep, find, exec, xargs

I have this find command to get all the files modified in the last 50 seconds which matchs with the following regex `hell\d` in the last 1000 characters.
I use tail to get the last 1000 chars in order to speed up the search becouse the files to check are huge (3gb on average).

```
find /home/ouhma -newermt '50 seconds' -type f |
while read fic; do
    if tail -c 1000 "${fic}" | LANG=C LC_ALL=C grep -Pq 'hell\d'; then
        echo "${fic}"
    fi
done
```

It is posible to use `-exec` parameter to replace that ugly loop and to retrieve the result even faster?

This works, but I dont know if its the best way to do it:

```
find /home/ouhma -newermt '50 seconds' -type f -exec bash -c 'LANG=C LC_ALL=C grep -Pq "hell\d" <(tail -c 1000 "{}") && echo "{}"' \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple `-exec` actions can follow one another, one `-exec` will be run if the previous `-exec` succeeds i.e. the command run by `-exec` returns exit status 0.

Do:

```
find /home/ouhma -type f -newermt '50 seconds' -exec env LC_ALL=C \
       bash -c 'grep -Pq "hell\d" <(tail -c 1000 "$1")' _ {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

As you are just printing the filename, this would suffice though:

```
find /home/ouhma -type f -newermt '50 seconds' -exec env LC_ALL=C \
       bash -c 'grep -Pq "hell\d" <(tail -c 1000 "$1") && echo "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: If I test your command by this way:
`find /home/ouhma/hello.txt -exec LC_ALL=C grep -Pq 'hell\d' <(tail -c 1000 {}) \; -exec echo {} \;`
It returns the following error:
`tail: cannot open '{}' for reading: No such file or directory
find: 'LC_ALL=C': No such file or directory`

Comment: Spawning a `bash` for every file won't be faster than OP's own attempt.

Comment: @anubhava True, check now.

Comment: Good but now it will scan full 3GB data not just last 1000 characters.

Comment: @anubhava Hmmm..chicken-egg problem i see :/

Comment: @anubhava what do you mean with your first comment? Thank you!

Comment: `-exec bash -c` forks a new child BASH process for each file in the output of `find` command. In theory, your `for` loop should perform better as you are operating on the final output of `find`

Comment: Ow! I get your point, @anubhava! We could test it using `time` command. I'm afraid I'm not be able to access my PC till tomorrow... :(

Comment: Could we use a similar (modified) version of your single command line code for our [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40053819/1527780) as well? It also involves the use of `find` , `locale` , `grep` , `mtime`