# How to negate two specific word in regex?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a file containing words, like these.

```
Good ones words:

művész-ként
luisz-ként
gravid-ként
chips-ként
bizottság-kent
Pannon-ként
Nagyostobafalva-kent

Words to remove:

font-size
line-height
X-Faktor
Calais-nál
```

What I need, is to remove the words containing a hyphen and the word after the hyphen is not 'ként' or 'kent'. The file also contains other words unhyphenated, that I have to keep (like "keresztül", "kod".....).

This could, but also eliminates the words that do not contain hyphen.

```
grep -vE "\w+-(kent|ként)     " file.txt
```

Comment: Maybe `grep P "\w+-(?!kent|ként)" file.txt`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This does'nt works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl's look-around assertions might simplify the solution:

```
perl -Mutf8 -CS -ne 'print unless /-(?!k[eé]nt)/' < file
```

- `-Mutf8` turns on UTF-8 in the source (i.e. makes the `é` work in the regex)
- `-CS` turns UTF-8 on for the input and output
- The regex says: dash *not followed* by `kent` or `ként`

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`, you can do:

```
grep -E '^(\w+-k[eé]nt|[^-]*)$' file
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fKlXRB/6)

This will find hyphenated words ending with `kent` or `ként` or words with no hyphen.

Comment: I face an [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40053819/1527780) with grep as well. Could you please have a look?