# How to loop a line of values using ',' and the print it as a list. Unix Korn Shell

Tags: shell, loops, for-loop, delimiter, cut

I'm trying to loop a file using a delimiter with a ',' and the print out those values in a "list" but I'm not sure how to get all the values of delimiter.

I have a file with emails like this (all in one line):

`test1@mail.com,test2@mail.com,test3@mail.com`

and my script is like this:

```
EmailsFile="/dev/fs/C/Users/myuser/Desktop/EMAILSTOREAD.txt"

for email in $(cat ${EmailsFile} | cut -d "," -f 1-100)
do
   echo "${email}\n"
done
```

I did 1-100 due I'm not sure how many values could have the file.

the output that I'm getting is:

`test1@mail.com,test2@mail.com,test3@mail.com`

Expected output:

```
test1@mail.com
test2@mail.com
test3@mail.com
```

Any idea?

Comment: [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: ...beyond that, though -- which ksh version is this? ksh93? ksh88? some random clone written by a person other than David Korn?

Comment: not sure what ksh is it, how can I check that?

Comment: @JavierSalas: From within `ksh`, run `echo $KSH_VERSION`.

Comment: I got this:
@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2 [SUA: 2009/04/01][i18n]

Comment: pdksh? Ewwww. Everything I'm saying about "exceptionally high-performance" does not at all apply. Consider installing the real thing.

Comment: ...to be clear, real David Korn ksh used to be commercial software that cost money (which is why pdksh, mksh, etc were created), but since 2005 it's been freely available licensed under the EPL, so there's no excuse for using a clone.

Comment: I'm just using a korn shell that runs under windows, is just for test, the real unix is in a server, but always I'm doing my test in my computer before it goes to the real one.

Comment: Consider using Microsoft's Ubuntu runtime -- there's a real ksh93 package for that.

Answer (score 3):

The following works with David Korn ksh93:

```
EmailsFile="/dev/fs/C/Users/myuser/Desktop/EMAILSTOREAD.txt"
while IFS=, read -r -A emails; do
    printf '%s\n' "${emails[@]}"
done <"$EmailsFile"
```

In general, avoid using `$()`, `cat`, `cut`, &c. unless absolutely necessary; they're far slower than shell builtin capabilities (especially in ksh, which is an exceptionally high-performance shell).

Comment: We would also like to use `cut` in a similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40053819/1527780) to receive all files under `find` and `grep`.

Comment: @marikamitsos, ...there's no good reason to use `cut` for that purpose. The safe way to read a list of times and arbitrary filenames from `find` is to use a `-printf` format string that puts a NUL after the name, and a character that can't exist in the timestamp between the time and the name, and to use two separate `read`s in each loop iteration to populate a variable for each value. (Newlines can exist in filenames, but NULs cannot, so `\n` is your format string is less safe than `\0`).

Comment: @marikamitsos, ...so, to do the read end safely in native bash, something like: `while IFS= read -r -d $'\t' timestamp && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do ...; done < <(find ... -printf '%T@\t%p\0')`

Comment: Thank you Charles. Could you please post this as an answer (preferably not in bash since I barely got my feet wet on command lines) under my original post?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: my bad, could not make the `-a` option work in `read` in my probably outdated `ksh` shell `version sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`. otherwise, `+1`

Comment: @Inian, it needs to be `-A`, not `-a`, for ksh (the latter is what bash uses). Should work in 93u+ with that change.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` as well:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' "$EmailsFile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr`:

```
tr "," "\n" < /dev/fs/C/Users/myuser/Desktop/EMAILSTOREAD.txt
```

When you want to add some words on each line, try

```
printf "found address %s in input\n" $(tr "," "\n" < /dev/fs/C/Users/myuser/Desktop/EMAILSTOREAD.txt
```